# How to upload Java archive (.WAR) to Windows Server on Plesk?

Tags: java, eclipse, plesk

I am able to create a `.WAR` archive of my Java project from Eclipse. This is what I tried:

`Plesk Home Page -> Domains -> example.com -> Java Applications -> Install Java Application`

But when I click The *Install Java Application* button it shows this warning:

```
There are no resources of this type (java application) available from your service provider.Requested 1; Available 0.
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give the warning as text. The image is unreadble.

Comment: please take a look again sir/madam.@Toto